# Can't set headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some basic authentication in a route that when used is throwing a console error.

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
    at ServerResponse.header
```

It only occurs when the "if" statement is true (the code within the if statement runs).  When that doesn't run, I am not getting any error and the "home" view renders without error.

```javascript
routes.get('/scan', (req, res, next) => {
    const orderID = req.query.order;
    const token   = req.query.token;

    if (!hasAccess(token))
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');

    res.render('home', {order});
});
```

Comment: Update your code to return after the `res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');` otherwise you will try to send a response AND render a page every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `return;` after your `res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');` to avoid sending a duplicate response.

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown when you try to respond more than one time to your request.

To avoid this kind of error, you should `return` when sending a response, so the function will not continue.

In your case :

```
routes.get('/scan',  (req, res, next) => {
  const orderID = req.query.order;
  const token   = req.query.token;

  if( !hasAccess( token ) )
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  return res.render('home', {order});
});
```

Comment: Returning at the end of the function (`return res.render(...)`) is not useful and can be omitted.

Comment: I agree, but it's common to do it, just by habits or to use tail call optimization on certain compilers

Comment: missing ); at the end of the routes.get() call.